# python script problem once build and package it

Tags: python, build, package

I've written python script to scan wifi and send data to the server, I set interval value, so it keep on scanning and send the data, it read from config.txt file where i set the interval value to scan, I also add yes/no in my config file, so is 'no' it will scan only once and if 'yes' it will scan according to the interval level,

my code as below

```
import time,.....

from threading import Event, Thread

class RepeatTimer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval, function, iterations=0, args=[], kwargs={}):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.iterations = iterations
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.finished = Event()

    def run(self):
        count = 0
        while not self.finished.is_set() and (self.iterations <= 0 or count < self.iterations):
            self.finished.wait(self.interval)
            if not self.finished.is_set():
                self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
                count += 1

    def cancel(self):
        self.finished.set()

    def scanWifi(self):
        #scanning process and sending data done here


obj = JW()
if status == "yes":
    t = RepeatTimer(int(intervalTime),obj.scanWifi)
    t.start()
else:
    obj.scanWifi()
```

once I package my code, its only run when I set my config file set to 'no' where it scan only once, but when I set my config file to 'yes', there is no progress at all, so I found that there is problem with my class RepeatTimer(Timer) once build, but don't know how to solve

can anyone help me

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the loop condition. Supposing that `is_set()` returns `False`, the second part is always `False`. While is `intervalTime` is not known, i think that it is positive (does has sense a negative interval time?) and `count` is never lesser than `self.iterations`: they are both `0`.

But the code you posted is too few, it is not given to know how exactly works.

```
    while not self.finished.is_set() and (self.iterations <= 0 or count < self.iterations):
```